# Imgur API request using Java returns 400 status

Tags: java, get, imgur

I am trying to send a `GET` request to the Imgur API to upload an image.

When I use the following code I receive a `400` status response from the Imgur server - which, according to the [Imgur error documentation](http://api.imgur.com/error_handling#400), means I am missing or have incorrect parameters.

I know the parameters are correct as I have tested them directly in the browser URL (which successfully uploads an image) - so I must not be adding the parameters correctly within the code:

```
private void addImage(){
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("image", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("http://www.lefthandedtoons.com/toons/justin_pooling.gif", "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("myPublicConsumerKey", "UTF-8");

    // Send data
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        Logger.info( line );
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
}
```

This code is based on the API examples [provided by Imgur](http://api.imgur.com/examples#uploading_java).

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I may resolve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried including the optional `type` parameter with a value of `url`?

Comment: Also, just for the heck of it (since everything looks correct), try without the .json suffix and see if it works with an XML response.

Comment: does adding a conn.connect() after the wr.flush do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sample, ***imgur*** service returns 400 Bad Request status response with a non-empty body because of incorrect API key. In case of non successful HTTP response you shold read the response body from an error input stream. For example:

```
// Get the response
InputStream is;
if (((HttpURLConnection) conn).getResponseCode() == 400)
    is = ((HttpURLConnection) conn).getErrorStream();
else
    is = conn.getInputStream();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

And, by the way your example is POST, not GET, because you are sending the parameters in the request body instead of the URL.

Comment: Thanks DV13 - this helped a lot. I am indeed sending a POST so thank you for pointing that out. Using the error stream I find there is an issue with my key so I am going to dig deeper. Thanks again for this code - it saved me pulling my hair out for a little longer!